# Converting multiline code snippets in HTML to Markdown with pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I want to translate this snippet of HTML into Markdown using pandoc.

```html
<code class="code_block"># chown root:root /boot/grub/grub.cfg<br/># chmod og-rwx /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
</code>
```

The output I want to have, is something like this.

````
```
# chown root:root /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# chmod og-rwx /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```
````

But the output I never includes the `<br>` respectively a line break in the markdown file.

```
# chown root:root /boot/grub/grub.cfg# chmod og-rwx /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I already tried different commands and extensions.

```sh
$ pandoc -f html -t markdown t.html
$ pandoc -f html -t markdown+hard_line_breaks t.html 
$ pandoc -f html -t markdown+raw_html+hard_line_breaks t.html
$ pandoc -f html -t markdown+raw_html+hard_line_breaks-inline_code_attributes t.html
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the way pandoc represents inline code internally: the code is stored as a string of verbatim text together with a set of attributes. Newlines, being layout commands, don't fit into this representation and are ignored.

Note also that the above is a rather uncommon way of writing multi-line code. See, e.g., the [MDN docs on the `<code>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code):

> To represent multiple lines of code, wrap the `<code>` element within a `<pre>` element. The `<code>` element by itself only represents a single phrase of code or line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code block is not properly formatted as a code block. You need (at least) the following:

```html
<pre><code># chown root:root /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# chmod og-rwx /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
</code></pre>
```

In addition to the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-code-element), covered in @tarleb's answer, the Markdown rules also differentiate between a code **block** and a code **span** based solely on the existence (or not) of the `<pre>` tag.

Note that the original Markdown rules demonstrate a [code block](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) as generating this HTML:

> ```
> <pre><code>This is a code block.
> </code></pre>
> ```

A `<code>` tag wrapped in a `<pre>` tag. In contrast, the same rules demonstrate a [code span](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) generating this HTML:

> ```
> <p>Use the <code>printf()</code> function.</p>
> ```

Note that only the `<code>` tag is used, but it is only an inline span (wrapped in a `<p>`, not a block level element.

When Pandoc is converting from HTML back to Markdown it follows the same convention in reverse. Yes, you have `class="code_block"` set on your `<code>` tag, but Pandoc doesn't know what that means, nor should it. And yes, your `<code>` element is not wrapped in a `<p>`, but that is just poorly formed HTML (according to the HTML spec, `<code>` is not a block-level element, but [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#phrasing-content-2); that is, content which gets wrapped in a block-level element such as a `<p>` or a `<pre>` element).

And then there is the issue of your `<br>` tag. How would Pandoc know if that is part of the code or a styling hook? In fact, it doesn't. Which is why we use `<pre>` tags for multi-line code blocks. With the `<pre>` tag, whitespace is preserved. Therefore, you only need a newline character without the `<br>` tag.

For completeness, I realize that the original Markdown rules do not include fenced code blocks, so I will also point to the GitHub Flavored Markdown spec, which also demonstrates [fenced code blocks](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) as producing `<pre><code>` wrapped blocks. Naturally, to go in reverse, you would need to start with `<pre><code>` wrapped blocks to end up with fenced code blocks.